# Change the size of the footnote counter IN the footnote

Tags: footnotes, fontsize, footmisc

The footmisc package is quite useful for changing the layout/style of a footnote text itself. Eg:

```
\renewcommand\footnotelayout{\scriptsize}
```

However, how do you change the size of the footnote number/counter (not in the body of your document, but in the footnote itself). I don't see any reference to this in the footmisc package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to redefine `\@makefntext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
    \long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em\noindent
            \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\huge\@thefnmark}}#1}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Test\footnote{test}
Test\footnote{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: However, this now undoes the \renewcommand\footnotelayout{\scriptsize} command :)

Comment: This will fix that problem FYI:

\makeatletter
    \long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em\noindent \footnotelayout \scriptsize
            \hb@xt@0.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\tiny\@thefnmark}}#1}%
\makeatother