# How to change the fontsize of footnote's number (not the fontsize of footnote)?

Tags: footnotes, fontsize

I need to change the fontsize of footnote's number (not the fontsize of footnote), see attachment. I try to find the answer but failed.

Give me a help!

John

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65892

Comment: Yes, it is the answer!